# Using CSS sprite on two images both

Tags: css, sprite, css-sprites

I'm using this html code for my buttons :

```
<a id="my-button" class="btn" name="my-button" href="#">
<span>Some text</span>
</a>
```

My button is actually composed of two images defined in CSS (i'm using sprites CSS):

```
.btn {
    background-image: url(images/btn-left.png);
}

.btn:hover {
    background-position:0 -27px;
}

.btn span {
    background-image: url(images/btn-right.png);
}

.btn span:hover {
    background-position:0 -27px;
}
```

I can put text of any size in the span. When I'm over the span, the left and the right button are modified, but when i'm just hover the a tag (a few pixels image) there is just the left button is changed, not the right...

How to change the span style when I'm hover the a tag please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write like this:

```
.btn:hover {
    background-position:0 -27px;
}
.btn:hover span{
    background-position:0 -27px;
}
```

OR

If background position is same then write like this:

```
.btn:hover, .btn:hover span {
        background-position:0 -27px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need to have the span? Why not use one sprite image so you only need to load one image and have something like:

```
<a class="btn" name="my-button" href="#">
Some text
</a>
```

and use CSS to process the hover state.

```
.btn {
   width: xxx;
   height: xxx;
   background-image: url(images/btn-left.png);
   background-position:top; /* use one long image with both states for active and    hover */
   display:block;
}
.btn:hover {
  background-position:bottom; /* moves the image down on hover to the lower part of the image */
}
```

I've made a little example, obviously just using color instead of image. Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/kkj8n/

Just switch background color to image and use background-position to operate the change in position.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I can not use this code because I use the internationalization, and text can be longer or shorter.